# WebView2 restrict to navigation only

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webview2, kiosk

I'm making an application for a kiosk setup on a Windows OS, this application uses a WebView2 control to display a website in a panel. The user should be able to navigate around the website by following links he sees. His sole input method is a touch screen that acts as a mouse.

I'm trying to prevent the user from "escaping" or accessing unwanted functions such as :

- Opening new windows
- **Downloading files**
- **Accessing the printing dialog** (access generally found when viewing a PDF, in the toolbar)
- **Accessing other applications through "mail:to" links**

I've so far only been able to prevent new windows from being opened through the "CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested" event. Is there any settings or events I could use to disable the previous behaviors ?

I'd prefer if these settings could be all set inside the code, but editing Microsoft Edge's settings or registry keys is also acceptable as a workaround.

Comment: You know that windows has a dedicated kiosk mode? - https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+11+kiosk+mode

Comment: @RandRandom The program will be deployed on machines that don't all have that mode available and updating the OS on all of them would not be practical unfortunately.